# Why can't I dynamically allocate memory of this string of a struct?

Tags: c, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation, strcpy

Let's say for example, I have a struct:

```
typedef struct person {
    int id;
    char *name;
} Person;
```

Why can't I do the following:

```
void function(const char *new_name) {
    Person *human;

    human->name = malloc(strlen(new_name) + 1);
}
```

Comment: You have a pointer to a human, but you haven't allocated new space for the human itself.

Comment: @user2899162: sounds more like a failed domestic policy than a programming problem!

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate space for `human` first:

```
Person *human = malloc(sizeof *human);

human->name = malloc(strlen(new_name) + 1);
strcpy(human->name, new_name);
```

Comment: Don't you mean to malloc the size of the struct not just a pointer? @barmar   -sizeof(*huamn

Answer (score 0):

You have to allocate memory for the structure `Person`. The pointer should point to the memory allocated for the structure. Only then you can manipulate the structure data fields.

The structure `Person` holds `id,` and the `char` pointer `name` to the name. You typically want to allocate memory for the name and copy the data into it.
At the end of the program remember to release memory for the `name` and the `Person`.
Release order is important.

Small sample program  to illustrate the concept is presented:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct person {
    int id;
    char *name;
} Person;


Person * create_human(const char *new_name, int id) 
{
    Person *human = malloc(sizeof(Person));       // memory for the  human

    human->name = malloc(strlen(new_name) + 1);   // memory for the string
    strcpy(human->name, new_name);                // copy the name

    human->id = id;                               // assign the id 

    return human; 
}

int main()
{
    Person *human = create_human("John Smith", 666);

    printf("Human= %s, with id= %d.\n", human->name, human->id);

    // Do not forget to free his name and human 
    free(human->name);
    free(human);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Human= John Smith, with id= 666.
```